# executing the javascript code in address bar

Tags: javascript, firefox

I really don't know whether i am supposed to ask such question here or not. But anyways,

I am trying to run the following javascript code on address bar*:

```
javascript:if ( document.getElementById('meebo') ) document.getElementById('meebo').style.display='none';
```

<strike>this meebo bar on any website is just an annoyance :x</strike> . Now the problem i am facing is, when i press return, it shows the page with only 'none' written on it. Try it on <strike>http://www.hongkiat.com</strike> any website having meebo bar installed on it.

Another problem is, i want this code to be executed every time any page is displayed. I think we can do this using greasemonkey, but i am sure there will be another easier answer.

*by saying `run on address bar`, i mean copy the above code and paste it to address bar and hit return.

Comment: Are you wanting to add this JS into a page you are writing or to everypage you look at?

Comment: everypage, say google.com, yahoo.com, blah-blah.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap this in a function:

```
javascript:(function(){if(document.getElementById('meebo'))document.getElementById('meebo').style.display='none'})();
```